# Remove first 10 characters from a string in C?

Tags: c, string, file

I've got a string:

```
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz
```

And I want to remove the first 10 characters, so that the start of the string would be the name of the CPU.

Essentially, how do I remove the first whitespaces, but not the ones in the actual name? Or, how do I remove the first 10 characters of this string?

Answer (score 2):

> how do I remove the first 10 characters

Simply add 10 to your character pointer. Though in your example, you seem to actually need 18, not 10.

Comment: What if the string was dynamically allocated ? Now you can't free it (unless you saved the original pointer before adding 10)

Comment: @John3136 You are correct that you need to save the original pointer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) to shift the contents of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OFFSET 18

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz";

    memmove(
        string,
        string + OFFSET,
        strlen(string) + 1 - OFFSET);

    printf("<<%s>>\n", string);
}
```

```
<<Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply offset by 18 chars (not the 10 mentioned in the question) if you simply want to access the trailing part of the string.

```
 char * pointer_to_cpu = &longstring[18];
```

If you want to permanently erase them the `memmove` answer is what you need

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers offered, if you need to save the string minus the first 10 characters as a separate item, without modifying the original:

```
strcpy(substr, &str[10]);
```

This assumes `substr` is a char array of sufficient size to avoid overflow.